# configure WSO2 identity provider 5.1 to integrate with SAML 1.1 service provider

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

my question is simple how to configure WSO2 identity provider 5.1 to integrate with SAML 1.1 service provider?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IS 5.1.0 using "SAML 2.0" not "SAML 1.1". Below link give you a details steps to add [service provider to the WSO2 IS 5.1.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On).

Comment: anyway to support SAML1.1? my SP just support SAML1.1